# oracle sqlcl via bash script unknown host specified error

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlcl

I have oracle VM in my virtualbox and from host OS I want to be able to run a shell script which would:
   1. put an .sql script into VM
   2. run the sqlcl and the .sql script on a VM

When I run oracle sqlcl from my host machine it throws an error - unknown host. 
Basically when I run sqlcl in VM machine bash it works, when I run it in a script that ssh(es) to the VM it doesn't work.

I'm sure I'm missing something very fundamental about users/ssh/sessions in linux. It would be great if somebody could point out what I should learn more about too.

my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p 'oracle' sftp -P 2200 oracle@127.0.0.1:/myscripts/ << END_OF_SFTP
    put foo
    pwd
    bye
END_OF_SFTP

sshpass -p 'oracle' ssh -p 2200 oracle@127.0.0.1 << END_OF_SSH
    who
    cd /myscripts/
    ./runscript hello_world.sql
END_OF_SSH
```

runscript is a script I put on my VM to run provided .sql scripts - this is how it looks:

```
#!/bin/bash
/u01/userhome/oracle/sqlcl/bin/sql hr/oracle @/myscripts/$1
```

output I get:

```
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Changing to: /myscripts/
sftp>   put foo
Uploading foo to /myscripts/foo
sftp>   pwd 
Remote working directory: /myscripts
sftp>   bye
#I have no idea what below lines mean :( 
#running sqlcl 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
oracle   :0           2019-08-03 06:26 (:0)
oracle   pts/0        2019-08-03 06:28 (:0)

SQLcl: Release 19.1 Production on Sat Aug 03 07:19:12 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

  USER          = hr
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORCL
  Error Message = IO Error: Unknown host specified
  USER          = hr
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORCL:1521/ORCL
  Error Message = IO Error: Unknown host specified
```